# How to catch error thrown by non existant sub-object in php?

Tags: php, plugins, error-handling

i am thinking hard about how to implement a good plugin-system in php. I read a lot about hooking systems and different ways to implement such things, but until now I did not find any approach or existing system that would fit my needs.

I want to have an object (let it be $plugins) in which all used plugins are available as sub-object ($plugin->$blog). So far, thats no problem. But how could I catch a non existant plugin?

If somewhere in the code I would call the plugin $blog by using $plugin->$blog->loadArticle or something similar and the plugin was not loaded by the plugin system, a fatal error would be thrown. Is it possible to catch and handle these errors within a debugging class?

Thanks for your thoughts! Please excuse my english... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can implement your Plugin object like this using magic __get()

```
class Plugins {
   private $plugins = array();

   public function __get($name) {
       if (!isset($this->plugins[$name]) {
          throw new PluginNotInstalledException(); //this can be catched with try / catch
       }
       return $this->plugins[$name];
   }

   ... //methods addPlugin() etc..
}
```

Comment: Basically, thats what I was looking for. But if I directly call $plugins->blog->getArticle I would get two errors. The first one would be caught, the second one (for the not defined function getArticle) still throws a fatal error. Can I catch this one too?

Comment: To catch the first is enough, second access won't be called at all.

Comment: It actually is. I just rewrote your example to something really object based. No more array in the functions, just trying to access the object directly. But I just realized, that I could deliver an "empty" plugin object which would catch the function call with __call().

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're setting your `$blog` property would be a good time to check whether the passed parameter is `=== NULL` and throw an exception if that's the case. So you'll be sure that `$plugin->blog` isn't null.

It would be even better if your plugins have to implement an interface or inherit an abstract class. So then whenever you're setting a property you can check whether the passed parameter is `instanceof` that class/interface.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to provide a getPlugin() method.

```
function getPlugin($plugin)
{
  if(! isset($this->$plugin)) return false;

  return $this->$plugin;
}

$blog = $plugins->getPlugin('blog');
if($blog === false)
{//error condition

}
```